# Android manifest alert

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Подскажите, почему в Eclipse в файле manifest проекта возникает такой алерт

```
    Not targeting the latest versions of Android; compatibility modes apply. Consider testing and updating this version. Consult the android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES javadoc for details.
```

на строках:

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
```

API 10 указал, тк под рукой есть только аппараты с 2.3.3 для тестирования, фактически API  выше v1 не использую. **Что ему от меня надо?** В русскоязычном интернете не нашел ответа, в англоязычном не понимаю, что они там советуют, алерт всё равно остаётся

Comment: А какой у Вас установлен SDK?

Comment: SDK 2.3.3 r2 API 10

Comment: А что вас конкретно смущает? В сообщении говорится лишь о том, что, поскольку вы не указали в качестве `target version` последнюю (19), то на версиях, старших API 10 могут применяться режимы совместимости.

Comment: Ничего, кроме того мысль о том, что моё приложение где-то может не запуститься, из за проблемы в этом месте.

Правильным и наиболее оптимальным будет поставить min sdk 8, target sdk 19, и при создании проекта поставить Compale with sdk 19?